# Blur event doesn't occur well when I install million.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, craco

My project is made with CRA(Create React App).
I just watched a React lecture, and I installed million.js.
https://million.dev/

But now, there's a serious problem with blur event handling.
blur event never occurs. So, I tried to uninstall million.js, then blur event works...

Then my Question

1. I did not use useRef hook in this project. If I use 'useRef', will I be able to overcome problem with blur event?
2. Why blur event doesn't work in million.js envirionment?
3. Except for this problems, what should I do to improve my codes?

The code below is part of my project with problem above.
my github JPoint-project, https://github.com/Koh-Du-Beom/JPoint-project.

You can see my code in components/UserInfo/Userinfo.tsx.
thank you for reading my article.

```
/*eslint-disable*/
import classes from '../../styles/FormStyles.module.css';
import ImageControler from '../ImageControler/ImageControler';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState, AppDispatch } from '../../stores/redux/store';
import { updateUserInfo } from '../../stores/redux/userSlice';
import Divider from '../Divider/Divider';
import { isValidAccountNumber, isValidEmail, isValidName, isValidPhoneNumber, isValidStudentNumber, } from '../../utils/regularExpression/isValidUserInfo';

//million-ignore
const UserInfo : React.FC = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState<string>('');
    const [grade, setGrade] = useState<string>('');
    const [major, setMajor] = useState<string>(''); //전공
    const [studentNumber, setStudentNumber] = useState<string>('');
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState<string>('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');
    
    const [bankAccount, setBankAccount] = useState<string>('');//계좌번호
    const [bankName, setBankName] = useState<string>(''); // 은행명
    const [bankBookImg, setBankBookImg] = useState<string>('');
    const [idCardImg, setIdCardImg] = useState<string>('');
    const [signImg, setSignImg] = useState<string>('');
    
    const [lastBlurTime, setLastBlurTime] = useState<number>(0);
    const [isValueChanged, setIsValueChanged] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState<{
        name?: string;
        grade?: string;
        major?: string;
        email?: string;
        phoneNumber?: string;
        studentNumber?: string;
        bankAccount?: string;
        bankName?: string;
    }>({});

    const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
    const userInfo = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.userInfo);

    const handleSaveButtonClick = () => {
        if(!isValueChanged){
            return;
        }
        setIsValueChanged(false);
        setLastBlurTime(0);
        
        dispatch(updateUserInfo({
            name: name,
      grade: grade,
      major: major,
      studentNumber: studentNumber,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      email: email,
      bankAccount: bankAccount,
      bankName: bankName,
      bankBookImg: bankBookImg,
      idCardImg: idCardImg,
      signImg: signImg,
        }));
        
  };

    const handleBlur = () => {
        setLastBlurTime(Date.now());
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (lastBlurTime === 0 || !isValueChanged) return;
        
        const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
            handleSaveButtonClick(); // 둘 다 비동기 함수지만 아래 코드가 먼저 실행될 수 있음. 그런 동작 막기위함
            setIsValueChanged(false);
        }, 1000); // 라우터(페이지 이동 시에도 실행되도록 하기)

        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }, [lastBlurTime, isValueChanged, handleSaveButtonClick])

    useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      setName(userInfo.name);
      setGrade(userInfo.grade);
      setMajor(userInfo.major);
      setStudentNumber(userInfo.studentNumber);
      setPhoneNumber(userInfo.phoneNumber);
      setEmail(userInfo.email);
      setBankAccount(userInfo.bankAccount);
      setBankName(userInfo.bankName);
      setBankBookImg(userInfo.bankBookImg || '');
      setIdCardImg(userInfo.idCardImg || '');
      setSignImg(userInfo.signImg || '');
    }       
        
  }, [userInfo]);

    const handleName = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newName = event.target.value;
        setName(newName);
        setIsValueChanged(true);
    };

    const handleNameBlur = () => {
        
        if (!isValidName(name)){
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, name : `${name? '올바른 이름이 아닙니다' : ''}`}));
            setName('');
            setIsValueChanged(false);
        }else{
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, name : undefined}));
            setLastBlurTime(Date.now());
        }
    };

    const handleGrade = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newGrade = event.target.value;
        setGrade(newGrade);
        setIsValueChanged(true);
    };

    const handleGradeBlur = () => {
        if (!isValidStudentNumber(grade)){
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, grade : `${grade? '올바른 학년이 아닙니다' : ''}`}));
            setGrade('');
            setIsValueChanged(false);
        }else{
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, grade : undefined}));
            setLastBlurTime(Date.now());
        }
    };

    const handleMajor = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newMajor = event.target.value;
        setMajor(newMajor);
        setIsValueChanged(true);
    };

    const handleMajorBlur = () => {
        if(!isValidName(major)){
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, major : `${major? '올바른 학과가 아닙니다' : ''}`}));
            setMajor('');
            setIsValueChanged(false);
        }else{
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, major : undefined}));
            setLastBlurTime(Date.now());
        }
    };

    const handleStudentNumber = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newStudentNumber = event.target.value;
        setStudentNumber(newStudentNumber);
        setIsValueChanged(true);
    };

    const handleStudentNumberBlur = () => {
        if (!isValidStudentNumber(studentNumber)){
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, studentNumber : `${studentNumber? '올바른 학번이 아닙니다' : ''}`}));
            setStudentNumber('');
            setIsValueChanged(false);
        }else{
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, studentNumber: undefined}));
            setLastBlurTime(Date.now());
        }
    };

    const handlePhoneNumber = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newPhoneNumber = event.target.value;
        setPhoneNumber(newPhoneNumber);
        setIsValueChanged(true);
    };

    const handlePhoneNumberBlur = () => {
        if (!isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)){
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, phoneNumber : `${phoneNumber? '올바른 연락처가 아닙니다' : ''}`}));
            setPhoneNumber('');
            setIsValueChanged(false);
        }else{
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, phoneNumber : undefined}));
            setLastBlurTime(Date.now());
        }
    };

    const handleEmail = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newEmail = event.target.value;
        setEmail(newEmail);
        setIsValueChanged(true);
    };

    const handleEmailBlur = () => {
        if (!isValidEmail(email)){
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, email : `${email? '올바른 이메일이 아닙니다' : ''}`}));
            setEmail('');
            setIsValueChanged(false);
        }else{
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, email : undefined}));
            setLastBlurTime(Date.now());
        }
    };


    const handleBankAccount = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newBankAccount = event.target.value;
        setBankAccount(newBankAccount);
        setIsValueChanged(true);
    };

    const handleBankAccountBlur = () => {
        if (!isValidAccountNumber(bankAccount)){
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, bankAccount : `${bankAccount? '올바른 계좌번호가 아닙니다' : ''}`}));
            setBankAccount('');
            setIsValueChanged(false);
        }else{
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, bankAccount : undefined}));
            setLastBlurTime(Date.now());
        }
    };

    const handleBankName = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newBankName = event.target.value;
        setBankName(newBankName);
        setIsValueChanged(true);
    };

    const handleBankNameBlur = () => {
        if(!isValidName(bankName)){
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, bankName : `${bankName? '올바른 은행명이 아닙니다' : ''}`}));
            setBankName('');
            setIsValueChanged(false);
        }else{
            setErrorMsg((prev) => ({...prev, bankName : undefined}));
            setLastBlurTime(Date.now());
        }
    };

    const handlebankBookImg = (file : File | null) => {
        if(file){
            convertToBase64(file, setBankBookImg);
            setIsValueChanged(true);
        }else{
            setBankBookImg('');
        }
        handleBlur();
    };

    const handleIdCardImg= (file : File | null) => {
        if(file){
            convertToBase64(file, setIdCardImg);
            setIsValueChanged(true);
        }else{
            setIdCardImg('');
        }
        handleBlur();
    };

    const handleSignImg = (file : File | null) => {
        if(file){
            convertToBase64(file, setSignImg);
            setIsValueChanged(true);
        }else{
            setSignImg('');
        }
        handleBlur();
    };

    const convertToBase64 = (file : File, callback: (base64String : string) => void) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            callback(reader.result as string);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
    };//fileReader 알아보기
    

    return (
        <form className={classes.container}>
            <div className={`${classes.wrapper} ${classes.end_double}`}>
                <div>
                    <div className={classes.big_title}>내 정보</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Divider/>      
            <div className={classes.big_title}>기본 정보</div>

            <div className={`${classes.wrapper} ${classes.double}`}>
                <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                    <div>
                        <div className={classes.small_title}>이름</div>
                        <input 
                            className={classes.input}
                            type='text'
                            onChange={handleName}
                            onBlur={handleNameBlur}
                            value={name}
                        />
                        {errorMsg.name && <div className={classes.errorMsg}>{errorMsg.name}</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                    <div>
                        <div className={classes.small_title}>학과</div>
                        <input
                            className={classes.input} 
                            type='text'
                            onChange={handleMajor}  
                            onBlur={handleMajorBlur}
                            value={major}
                        />
                        {errorMsg.major && <div className={classes.errorMsg}>{errorMsg.major}</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={`${classes.wrapper} ${classes.double}`}>
                <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                    <div>
                        <div className={classes.small_title}>학년</div>
                        <input 
                            className={classes.input}
                            type='text'
                            onChange={handleGrade}
                            onBlur={handleGradeBlur}
                            value={!grade ? '' : grade.toString()}
                        />
                        {errorMsg.grade && <div className={classes.errorMsg}>{errorMsg.grade}</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                    <div>
                        <div className={classes.small_title}>학번</div>
                        <input
                            className={classes.input} 
                            type='text'
                            onChange={handleStudentNumber}  
                            onBlur={handleStudentNumberBlur}
                            value={studentNumber}
                        />
                        {errorMsg.studentNumber && <div className={classes.errorMsg}>{errorMsg.studentNumber}</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={`${classes.wrapper} ${classes.double}`}>
                <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                    <div>
                        <div className={classes.small_title}>전화번호</div>
                        <input 
                            className={classes.input}
                            type='text'
                            onChange={handlePhoneNumber}
                            onBlur={handlePhoneNumberBlur}
                            value={phoneNumber}
                        />
                        {errorMsg.phoneNumber && <div className={classes.errorMsg}>{errorMsg.phoneNumber}</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                    <div>
                        <div className={classes.small_title}>이메일</div>
                        <input
                            className={classes.input} 
                            type='text'
                            onChange={handleEmail}  
                            onBlur={handleEmailBlur}
                            value={email}
                        />
                        {errorMsg.email && <div className={classes.errorMsg}>{errorMsg.email}</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <Divider/>  
            
            <div className={classes.big_title}>통장 및 신분증사본</div>
            <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                <div>
                    <div className={classes.small_title}>통장사본</div>
                    <ImageControler onImageChange={handlebankBookImg} data={bankBookImg}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={`${classes.wrapper} ${classes.double}`}>
                <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                    <div>
                        <div className={classes.small_title}>계좌번호</div>
                        <input
                            className={classes.input} 
                            type='text'
                            onChange={handleBankAccount}    
                            onBlur={handleBankAccountBlur}
                            value={bankAccount}
                        />
                        {errorMsg.bankAccount && <div className={classes.errorMsg}>{errorMsg.bankAccount}</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                    <div>
                        <div className={classes.small_title}>은행명</div>
                        <input 
                            className={classes.input}
                            type='text'
                            onChange={handleBankName}
                            onBlur={handleBankNameBlur}
                            value={bankName}
                        />
                        {errorMsg.bankName && <div className={classes.errorMsg}>{errorMsg.bankName}</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                <div>
                    <div className={classes.small_title}>신분증사본</div>
                    <ImageControler onImageChange={handleIdCardImg} data={idCardImg}/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                <div>
                    <div className={classes.small_title}>서명 사진</div>
                    <ImageControler onImageChange={handleSignImg} data={signImg}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

export default UserInfo;
```

My project is made with CRA(Create React App).
I just watched a React lecture, and I installed million.js.
But now, there's a serious problem with blur event handling.
blur event never occurs. So, I tried to uninstall million.js, then blur event works...

Then my Question

1. I did not use useRef hook in this project. If I use 'useRef', will I be able to overcome problem with blur event?
2. Why blur event doesn't work in million.js envirionment?

The code below is part of my project with problem above.
my github JPoint-project, https://github.com/Koh-Du-Beom/JPoint-project.

You can see my code in components/UserInfo/Userinfo.tsx.
thank you for reading my article.

Comment: Create-react-app has been "dead" for a long time now, and the React "getting started" docs don't even mention it exists (because for all intents and purposes, it doesn't). So: if this is a new project, don't use `create-react-app`, use [any of the actually mentioned solutions](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project) from the React docs instead.

Comment: I understood your comment and I just checked many React.js programmers use Vite instead. Thanks for your comment, I will try to migrate my project into Vite. But I'm still curious why blur event doesn't work well when I install million.js. Can I assume that million.js is not able to run in Create-react-app environment?

Comment: hard to say outright - one thing you'll want to do is split up your component because that's way too many state variables for a single component: use React for what it's best at, which is composing components out of components =) Make at least three smaller components, one for each of the "blocks" that you've used newline spacing for right now (and probably use fewer divs. You really don't need a div inside a div inside a div inside a div. A single level fieldset and some flexbox CSS will happily do what you need, here.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice. You mean this single UserInfo component has too many states, so It may be hard to manage problems. As your advice, I'm planning to divide this single component into 4 components. By doing this, I will be able to simplyfy my jsx code and be easier to understand jsx code as well. 
Regardless of problem about applying million.js , Your comment inspired me, so that I will be able to improve myself and be a better react programmer. Thank you